# Why medicine modelling is distributed on regular person's computers?

Tags: research

There are some distributed computing project on the Internet that tries to find cure for diseases, like [World Community Grid](https://www.worldcommunitygrid.org/discover.action#what-if). Could anyone say why there are such things and how useful those are? I mean, I believe that if you are serious researcher, I think you are able to use university's networks or supercomputers to do modelling. So what is the idea about spread the modelling to regular computers? Does the medicine modelling require so much computer power that computers in universities have not enough computing power?

Comment: Welcome to SE!  The Stack Exchange model works best when you ask only one question per post.  I count four questions in your post.  Also, it might help to narrow your question down.  I imagine that modelling is likely used for many different purposes.  The usefulness of modelling will probably depend on the specific instance.  Some might be a lot more useful than others.  So a broad question about the usefulness of modelling in general is probably not answerable.

Comment: This question is about distributed computing, which isn't unique to medicine by any means. It's used in many fields such as astronomy, chemistry, physics -- any field with problems requiring massive computing capacity. Therefore, it's off topic here. Unfortunately, the one site where I thought it might be welcome has declined it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about medical science as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how readily available supercomputers are to researchers and universities but I would imagine that a big part of the answer to your question would be down to cost.

### Supercomputers vs Distributed Computing Projects

Computer performance is measured in [FLOPS (Floating Point Operations Per Second)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS), and in June 2018, [Summit](https://www.top500.org/lists/2018/06), an IBM-built supercomputer now running at the Department of Energy’s (DOE) Oak Ridge National Laboratory (ORNL), captured the number one spot for the fastest computer performance at **122.3 petaFLOPS** on the [LINPACK benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks) where peta is 10<sup>15</sup>.  When compared to the home PCs, the fastest possible home PC processor at a cost of $2,000 provides [approx. 1 teraFLOPS](https://www.popsci.com/intel-teraflop-chip) where tera is 10<sup>12</sup>.

For distributed computing projects, let's look at [Folding@home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding@home).

> The project uses the idle processing resources of thousands of personal computers owned by volunteers who have installed the software on their systems. Its main purpose is to determine the mechanisms of protein folding, which is the process by which proteins reach their final three-dimensional structure, and to examine the causes of protein misfolding. This is of significant academic interest with major implications for medical research into Alzheimer's disease, Huntington's disease, and many forms of cancer, among other diseases. To a lesser extent, Folding@home also tries to predict a protein's final structureand determine how other molecules may interact with it, which has applications in drug design. Folding@home is developed and operated by the Pande Laboratory at Stanford University
>
> **[...]**
>
> Since its launch on October 1, 2000, the Pande Lab has produced 200 scientific research papers as a direct result of Folding@home [see https://foldingathome.org/papers-results]

Stats provided by Folding@home at https://stats.foldingathome.org/os state that their project provides a total performance of 47,344 Native teraFLOPS or 98,747 x86 teraFLOPS.

[image: Folding@home stats by OS]

Note that these teraFLOPS values are from the software cores, not the peak values from CPU/GPU specs and these figures only just beat the performance of China's Sunway TaihuLight in 2016 which was ranked the world's fastest with 93 petaFLOPS on the LINPACK benchmark ([now the 2nd fastest supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunway_TaihuLight)).

### Cost

IBMs Summit Supercomputer [cost $200 million to build](https://qz.com/1301510/the-us-has-the-worlds-fastest-supercomputer-again-the-200-petaflop-summit) and according to Wikipedia, the Sunway TaihuLight cost $273 million.  When you consider the computing performance provided by Folding@home is provided by volunteers (so the system is free), it is a no brainer that the computing power on offer should not be turned away.

Comment: Super Computers are also  relatively expensive to rent out being intended for a shorter period (hours,days,weeks), for example cirrus in the uni of edinburgh would cost nearly £400 or so per hour to rent(https://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/facilities/demand-computing/cirrus) and is less powerful than the folding at home network.

Where as a project like folding at home is looking to work on the same task for a much longer period of time and over the years folding at home has been running the value of the donated computer power would add up substantially and requires a lot less upfront cost.

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from direct statement: supercomputer: 122PFLOPS/$273M vs F@H: 47PFLOPS/$0. (it's not actually $0, it's the cost of work of people who wrote the client) It would also be nice to mention electricity costs.